# Laravel Eloquent - Do something before returning models from a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

We have some circular dependencies between a couple of models and we would like to optimize that.

Here is a quick overview of the DB schema

```
Person : id, main_address_id
Address: id, addressable_type, addressable_id
```

Which translates into Eloquent models:

```
class Person {
  function addresses() {
      return $this->morphMany(Address::class, 'addressable', 'addressable_type', 'addressable_id');     
  }

  function main_address() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'main_address_id');     
  }
}

class Address {
  public function addressable(): MorphTo
  {
      return $this->morphTo('addressable', 'addressable_type', 'addressable_id');
  }

  public function isMainAddress(): bool {
      return $this->id === $this->addressable?->main_address_id;
  }
}
```

Everything is working pretty good but we noticed we could save quite a lot of DB queries when dealing with the following type of code:

```
$addresses = $person->addresses;

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $address->isMainAddress(); // Loads the addressable from DB to check the IDs
}
```

One easy fix on the above code is to add a call to setRelation:

```
$addresses = $person->addresses->each(fn($a) => $a->setRelation('addressable', $person));
```

That way, the addressable relationship from each address is not queried.

All is fine in a simple case like that, we want to avoid manually doing the setRelation in each place we need it.

Basically we are looking for a way to run a callback on the models returned by the relationship after each time it gets queries. Something like that basically:

```
  function addresses() {
      return $this->morphMany(Address::class, 'addressable', 'addressable_type', 'addressable_id')
          ->prepareModels(fn($a) => $a->setRelation('addressable', $this));     
  }

  function main_address() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'main_address_id')
          ->prepareModels(fn($a) => $a->setRelation('addressable', $this));     
  }
```

---

**Kindly note that this is a pure Laravel question. I am not looking for advice regarding how the DB schema would be better another way.**

Comment: That's what happens when you over complicate your DB structure. as you can see `isMainAddress` is better as an attribute of the entity address rather than a second relation between Person and Address. Plus, the morph relation is complicating things. I suggest you consider simplifying your structure

Comment: Thanks, but in that case my question would be « how can I simplify my DB schema ». I am aware the schema is not ideal, but we have the same kind of pattern in 4 different models, with 4 or 5 different relationships and types of address/phone number/email address/establishment type/etc. with a 5 year accumulation of data, and that schema in production.

Hence I am not asking for trouble in « changing the schema for 300+ customer DB ». Just an easy way to let Laravel know he has to do something after he loads the models.

Comment: There is no built in ways to do what you're trying to do cause, if both models of a relation had that kind of callback feature, it would lead to an infinite loop. Why dont you move the logic of mainAdress check on the addressable entity as your structure suggest.

Comment: Because in some cases (for instance a API resources) we want to embed the « is_main » attribute in the AddressResource. I have already quite wrapped my head around potential fixes which would work around that (changing DB schema, changing the location of the method) and my current conclusion is either : A/ do that manually in each place we need it. B/ get the Eloquent callback working in order to get this automatically everywhere.

Comment: Or C/ make a migration that adds the field on the address directly, and updates it with existing data and once confirmed, make a migration to remove the foreign key on the addressable entities tables.